# How can I indicate to the user which textBox is empty or null?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a WinForm application with 9 TextBox controls. How can I alert the user which textboxes are empty or null?

```
var incompleteTextBoxes = this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>().Where(tb => string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(tb.Text));    
foreach (var textBox in inCompleteTextBoxes)
{
    // give user feedback about which text boxes they have yet to fill out
}
```

Comment: `MessageBox.Show("your message here")`

Comment: Use [ErrorProvider](http://www.dotnetperls.com/errorprovider)

Comment: I don't understand the problem. HOW do you want to give the user feedback?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most common practise is use [User input validation](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13922/Validate-user-input-in-Windows-Forms).

You can use [ErrorProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.errorprovider.aspx) class to *validate* and *notify* to the user.

Answer (score 0):

i would just create a method:

```
public void CheckField(string text, string textBoxName)
{
   if(text == null || text == string.Empty)
   {
        MessageBox.Show(this, textBoxName + " is empty, please fill it",
            "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
   }
}
```

and call it with each textbox

```
CheckField(textBox1.Text, "First Name");
CheckField(textBox2.Text, "Last Name");
CheckField(textBox3.Text, "ID");
CheckField(textBox4.Text, "Password");
.
.
.
```